# Xpath | operator inside the path

Tags: xpath, operators

I have an xpath as follows:

```
.//*[text()='Name:']/../child::select | .//*[text()='Name:']/../child::span
```

However for me it's not very compact nor elegant, I'd prefer something along the lines of:

```
.//*[text()='Name:']/../child::(select|span)
```

But the above solution does not work.
The idea is that the text (e.g. `'Name:'` is passed as an argument to a function, and it returns the node that might be of type either select or span.

Would appreciate help greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `|` operator with `self`:

```
.//*[text()='Name:']/../child::*[self::span | self::select]
```

The `child::` is the default, so it could be shortened to

```
.//*[text()='Name:']/../*[self::span | self::select]
```